# Zend custom Route not working if Index controller is not capitalized?

Tags: zend-framework, shared-hosting, zend-route

I'm testing a Zend project on my shared-hosting.I keep everything inside a folder 'Zend-project' not on the server public-root (cause I have there another project!).

this is the structure:

```
/public_root
  /zend-project
    /application
      /configs
        application.ini
      /controllers
      /layouts
      /views
      bootstrap.php
    /css
    /images
    /javascript
    /zend-library
    .htaccess
    index.php
```

I had to tweak a little the project cause I just can't change my document_root on a shared-hosting so I edited the .htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/favicon.ico$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /zend-project/index.php [NC,L]
```

but at the end everything seems to work fine except a single Url Route that I added to the router in my bootstrap.

**edit:I tried creating a new controller 'TestController'..with a single action (called 'test')I tried to type the url with the controller lowercase (mysite.com/zend-project/test/test)and it's working!As I suspected there is something wrong with the 'index' word itself!cause any other controller works as a charme**

this is bootstrap.php

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

protected function _initRoutes()
{

    $frontController=Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router=$frontController->getRouter();  
    $router->removeDefaultRoutes();
    $router->setGlobalParam('lang','en');
    $router->addRoute(
            'lang',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':lang/:controller/:action',
            array('lang'=>':lang',
            'module'=>'default',
            'controller'=>'index',
            'action'=>'index'

            )

            )
    );


            //the following route is not working remotely.
            //Is working on local environment
    $router->addRoute(
    'langController',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':controller/:action',
    array(

            'module'=>'default',
            'controller'=>'index',
            'action'=>'index'
            )

    )
);

            $router->addRoute(
    'langIndex',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':lang',
    array('lang'=>':lang',
            'module'=>'default',
            'controller'=>'index',
            'action'=>'index'
            )

    )
 );

            $router->addRoute(
    'langNothing',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('',
    array(
            'module'=>'default',
            'controller'=>'index',
            'action'=>'index'
            )

    )
);

}
}
```

I tried to type the following urls (based on the custom routes I created)and everithing seems to work:

```
//this points to the pair controller/action -> index/index
mysite.com/zend-project/

//this points to the pair controller/action ->index/index in english lang
mysite.com/zend-project/en

//this points to the pair controller/action ->index/rooms in english lang
mysite.com/zend-project/en/index/rooms
```

But whenever I type:

```
mysite.com/zend-project/index/index
```

I receive the following message:
    Not Found.The requested URL /zend-project/index/index was not found on this server.

It looks like the request doesn't reach the index.php file ..maybe an .htaccess problem??or what

thanks

**edited**

Found out that by typing the broken route's controller with capital letter it works :

```
//this works.Controller has capital letter
mysite.com/zend-project/Index/index 

//this do not work.Controller has not capital letter
mysite.com/zend-project/index/index
```

why??
(by the way I'm on linux server..)

Comment: this is strange problem. I wonder how `mysite.com/zend-project/Index/index ` works as first index indicated about the module but you are not having index module.? Can you please put the class names your controller too?

Comment: I specified a route 'langController' that handles situation when you type in :controller/:action..the point is in this case the controller has to be with Capital letter..my Index controller file is IndexController.php and the class name is IndexController

Comment: dude try the url like `mysite.com/zend-project/langNothing`

Comment: I tried.it shows the index action..why??

Comment: Are you not going to access this action?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4414/discussion-between-luca-and-awais-qarni)

Comment: How did you resolved this problem?

Comment: I renamed the controller =S ...turn around

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from httpd.conf

`Options Includes ExecCGI MultiViews FollowSymLinks Indexes`